# Does the ListObjects command guarantee the results are sorted by key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When calling the S3 ListObjects command (via either REST or SOAP API), is the result set returned in any particular order? I would expect, given the nature of object keys and markers, that the result set is always sorted by object key. But I haven't seen any documentation confirming this.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Update**: Amazon has changed their documentation as shown below.

<s>They are returned alphabetically</s>. List results are always returned in UTF-8 binary order. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html

> Amazon S3 exposes a list operation
>   that lets you enumerate the keys
>   contained in a bucket. Keys are
>   selected for listing by bucket and
>   prefix. For example, consider a bucket
>   named 'dictionary' that contains a key
>   for every English word. You might make
>   a call to list all the keys in that
>   bucket that start with the letter "q".
>   **<s>List results are always returned in
>   lexicographic (alphabetical) order</s> List results are always returned in UTF-8 binary order**.

Comment: This is nice but it doesn't specify if the order is ascending or descending.
With the little test I made it seems to be ascending...

Comment: What does UTF-8 binary mean ? Is it UTF-8 binary encoding of the key name ?

Comment: Ascending would be the default assumption, I'd say.

Comment: Also, the value of the key is what is referenced here, as far as I can tell. Would be nice if the docs elaborated a bit more, though!

Comment: If you could enhance this answer explaining "What does UTF-8 binary mean?" that would be awesome

Comment: it means it compares the number resulting from encoding the characters to UTF-8. This comparison method is very fast. When we say "sort alphabetically" it does not specify whether lowercase characters should be listed in front of or after uppercase characters. For most practical purposes it should do what you want :-)