# S3 ListObjectsV2Request sort parameter

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can list the `maxKeys` items from `bucketName` bucket as:

```
new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucketName).withMaxKeys(maxKeys)
```

If the bucket has more objects than `maxKeys`, I would like to fetch the 'maxKeys' oldest ones.

How can I fetch the `maxKeys` oldest ones? Is there a way to add a sort parameter to my list request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The `ListObjects` API call does not have a sort parameter.

From [Listing object keys programmatically - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html):

> List results are always returned in UTF-8 binary order.

(Reference found on: [Does the ListBucket command guarantee the results are sorted by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656391/174777))